# Asp.net mvc web application not running under the impersonate user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, impersonation

I have an asp.net mvc application and I have set up impersonation as follows in the web.config.

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  <authentication mode="Windows">
  </authentication>
  <identity impersonate="true" userName="BvhHisPharmaUser" password="12345"/>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

As you can see I have **enabled windows authentication mode**.
Next you can see **impersonate = true**. And the **userName(BvhHisPharmaUser)** is a windows user that I created as follows using **compmgmt.msc** tool.

[image: impersonate windows user]

Now when I place a break point in Index Home

[image: Immediate Window not showing the impersonate User]

I dont see the imperonate user in the identity in the immediate window.

What am I missing?

Even after I login using the login screen, I do not see the impersonate user in the immediate window as follows.

[image: Immediate windows after login]

I have removed the windows authentication mode in the web.config completely

and still observe exactly the same.

My objective is to run this iis web app under the above shown windows user(BvhHisPharmaUser) because this web app calls a wcf service which is configured to authorize this user.

So my questions are as follows.

1. Is impersonation is the way for this, so that the web application can run under this user? Is there any other way like app pool configuration?
2. Why is this impersonation not working? I have enabled it as showin in the web.config and still the identity of the thread principal does not change. What am I missing?

Kindly let me know if additional info is needed.

Comment: What Identity is used when it calls the WCF application?

Comment: Wow...its MachineName\\BvhHisPharmaUser. I just noticed it. Thank you Philips this gave me some direction to work on.